# Error: The getter 'u' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Guide me on what went wrong?

here is the whole error message.

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2103 in debug mode...
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);7u
^
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);7u
^
: Error: The getter 'u' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'.

- 'AssetBundleImageProvider' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'u'.
data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);7u
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Muhammad Umar\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Muhammad Umar\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

```
file 1 "main.dart"
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/welcome_page.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const WelcomePage(),
    );
  }
}

file 2 "welcome_page.dart"
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  List images = [
    "welcome-one.png",
    "welcome-two.png",
    "welcome-three.png",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (_,index){
          return Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: double.maxFinite,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  "img/"+images[index]
                ))
            ),
          );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that produced this exception.

Comment: I've updated the question now you can see the used file/code in there.

Comment: If you can share the images too with google drive

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/n5s5yiQnhYmFzVs1A

Comment: Can you include an image of your image location on project and also check the `pubspec.yaml` path

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/BpQozKBTPmE749iAA