# Exception caught by image resource service(already added assets in pubspec.yaml file)

Tags: flutter, exception, flutter-dependencies

Having this error **"Exception caught by image resource service".**
I already have added assets in **pubspec.yaml** file but still getting this **error** does anyone know why?
all files and resulting error is written down.
**Images** used in the project are "https://photos.app.goo.gl/n5s5yiQnhYmFzVs1A".

**file #1 main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/welcome_page.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const WelcomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**file #2 welcome_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  List images = [
    "welcome-one.png",
    "welcome-two.png",
    "welcome-three.png",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (_,index){
          return Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: double.maxFinite,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  "img/"+images[index]
                ))
            ),
          );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml file**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - img\welcome-one.png
    - img\welcome-two.png
    - img\welcome-three.png
```

**error message**

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: img/welcome-one.png
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "img/welcome-one.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#acc1c(), name: "img/welcome-one.png", scale: 1.0)
```

Comment: perhaps `img/welcome-one.png` instead of `img\welcome-one.png` in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The getter 'u' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160327/error-the-getter-u-isnt-defined-for-the-class-assetbundleimageprovider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a folder in the root of your project (same level as `lib` folder) called `img`, then the only issue I see is that you need to use forward slash, not back slash in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
// changing \ to /

 assets:
    - img/welcome-one.png 
    - img/welcome-two.png
    - img/welcome-three.png
```

You also don't need to specify each image you can shorten it to this

```
 assets:
    - img/
```

That will target everything in the `img` folder.